# The Ñ function. Where is this chaotic tweak of the geometric series continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let us consider the function $\nu:(-1,1)\to[-1,1]$ defined as follows
$$\nu(x):=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } x=0\\ \frac{1}{\left\lfloor \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor} & \text{ if } x\neq0\end{cases}$$
noticing that, since $\lfloor t+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor$ is the rounding function, it is the case that $\nu(x)\approx \frac{1}{x^{-1}}=x=\text{Id}(x)$. So we might see this function as a *tweak function* that takes every number of $(-1,1)$ to its *closest* one in $S:=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}^*\}$. But this function alone is not that much of a deal. For instance, its continuity is quite easy to study. It is continuous everywhere except at the points $(-1,1)\cap\{\frac{2}{n}: n\text{ odd}\}$ since the rounding function jumps precisely when $t=n+\frac{1}{2}$.

Now, I wanted to examine what would happen if I tweaked known well behaved series with this function. For this reason, I considered the series $\tilde N:(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $\tilde N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \nu(x^n)$ which looks like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ctzwttexm1).

[image: Plot of the function in Desmos] $ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ $
[image: Zoom in the negative part]

My main questions are on how to study its continuity. More precisely:

> 1. Is this function continuous at $S=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}^*\}$?
> 2. Is this function discontinuous at $(-1,1)\cap\{\frac{2}{n}:n \text{ odd}\}$?
> 3. Precisely when is it continuous/discontinuous?
> 4. What is happening where the domain is negative? (Reminds me of the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map))

Though the $3$rd one is the one that I really care for. Now I will prove the things that I know although they aren't that much.

$\color{green}{\bf{Proposition\ 1.}}$ $\tilde N(x)$ converges absolutely on $(-1,1)$. Hence, it is well defined.

*Proof.* Notice that it can be easily checked that $|\nu(x)|\leq\frac{3}{2}|x|$. Because of this, we know that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |\nu(x^n)|\leq \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{1-|x|}$.$\quad\Box$

$\color{green}{\bf{Proposition\ 2.}}$ If we consider $N(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$, then $\forall x\in S:\tilde N(x)=N(x)$.

*Proof.* If $x=0$ then $\tilde N(0)=1=N(0)$. Now, if $x=\frac{1}{m}$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}^*$ then the series becomes
$$\tilde N\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\lfloor m^n+1/2\rfloor}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{m^n}=N\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)\quad\Box$$

---

**Update:** It is quite easy to show that $\tilde N$ is continuous at $0$ by bounding the $\nu$ function.

$\color{seagreen}{\bf{Lemma\ 1.}}$ If $x\in(-1,1)$ is such that $|x|<\frac{2}{k}$ for some odd $k\geq1$ then $\frac{k}{k+1}|x|\leq|\nu(x)|\leq\frac{k+2}{k+1}|x|$.

[*Proof.*](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/klqbn0pwjq) This can be easily checked by making use of known inequalities of the floor function.

[image]

$$|x|<\frac{2}{k}\Rightarrow \color{blue}{\frac{k}{k+1}|x|}\leq\color{purple}{|\nu(x)|} \leq \color{red}{\frac{k+2}{k+1}|x|}$$

$\color{green}{\bf{Proposition\ 3.}}$ The $\tilde N(x)$ function is continuous at $x=0$.

*Proof.* There are several ways of formalizing it but the idea is to make use of the above lemma since it is saying that $\nu(x)\sim x$ as $x\to0$. We will examine $\lim_{x\to0^+}\tilde N(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-}\tilde N(x)$ to see that they are both equal to $1=\tilde N(0)$ and, consequently, to see that $\tilde N$ is indeed continuous at $0$.

Suppose that $0<x<\frac{2}{k}$ for odd $k\geq3$. Then we know that $\frac{k}{k+1}x\leq\nu(x)\leq\frac{k+2}{k+1}x$ which implies that, since $\frac{k}{k+1}\leq\nu(1)\leq\frac{k+2}{k+1}$ is trivially true (as $\nu(1)=1$) and $\forall n\geq1:x^n\leq x<2/k$ (as $0<x<1$), the following inequalities hold
$$\underline{\frac{k}{k+1}}\leq\frac{k}{k+1}\frac{1}{1-x}\leq\underline{\tilde N(x)}\leq\frac{k+2}{k+1}\frac{1}{1-x}\leq\underline{\frac{k+2}{k+1}\frac{1}{1-2/k}}$$
which implies $\lim_{x\to0^+}\tilde N(x)=1$ by the squeeze theorem since both bounds tend to $1$ as $k\to+\infty$. The limit from the left, however, is somewhat trickier. But not that much, to be fair. The idea is to notice that $\text{sign}(\nu(x))=\text{sign}(x)$. Thus, if $x<0$, we have that $\nu(x^n)=(-1)^n|\nu(x^n)|$. With this in mind, let's study the other limit.

Suppose now that $-\frac{2}{k}<x<0$ for odd $k\geq3$. Let's try to bound $\tilde N(x)$ with bounds that only depend on $k$ that tend to $1$ as $k\to+\infty$. As an upper bound, we have
\begin{align*}
\tilde N(x) &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty|\nu(x^{2n})|-\sum_{n=0}^\infty|\nu(x^{2n+1})|\leq\sum_{n=0}^\infty|\nu(x^{2n})|\leq\frac{k+2}{k+1}\frac{1}{1-x^2}\leq\frac{k+2}{k+1}\frac{1}{1-4/k^2}
\end{align*}
and, as a lower bound, we have
\begin{align*}
\tilde N(x) &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty|\nu(x^{2n})|-\sum_{n=0}^\infty|\nu(x^{2n+1})|\geq\frac{k}{k+1}\frac{1}{1-x^2}-\frac{k+2}{k+1}\frac{|x|}{1-x^2}\\
&=\frac{k-(k+2)|x|}{(k+1)(1-x^2)}\geq\frac{k-(k+2)\frac{2}{k}}{(k+1)(1-x^2)}\geq\frac{k-2-\frac{4}{k}}{k+1}\end{align*}
which, finally, implies that $\lim_{x\to0^-}\tilde N(x)=1$ as well. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Do you have any questions that you want answered?

Comment: @K.defaoite: Yes, precisely where is the function $Ñ$ continuous?